# Creating multiple rows in an MS SQL table per row in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has a unique ID per row, and I have another table which has a column for the same ID plus some others. What I'd like to do is for every row in the first table, create multiple rows in the second table with the same ID but different values that are set manually. I  only need to do this as a once off for existing data. Something like:

```
insert into person.rooms(personID, roomID, isDecorated)
values (personID, 0, 1),
       (personID, 1, 1),
       (personID, 2, 0),
       (personID, 3, 0)
select personID from person.rooms
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some portion of data from each table?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output from this new table?

Comment: What exactly about this do you not know how to do?   It sounds like a simple INSERT to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need values clause here, but multiple UNION ALL select statements as below:

```
insert into person.rooms(personID, roomID, isDecorated)

select personID, 0, 1 from person.rooms
UNION ALL
select personID, 1, 1 from person.rooms
UNION ALL
select personID, 2, 0 from person.rooms
UNION ALL
select personID, 3, 0 from person.rooms
```

Or you could use `CROSS APPLY` something like this....

```
insert into person.rooms(personID, roomID, isDecorated)
SELECT C.personID, C.RoomID, C.isDecorated 
FROM person.rooms t
     CROSS APPLY (values (t.personID, 0, 1),
                         (t.personID, 1, 1),
                         (t.personID, 2, 0),
                         (t.personID, 3, 0) )c( personID,RoomID, isDecorated)
```

Comment: I took the first option and it worked great, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the number in TOP(100) , for the number of rows you want to insert

```
Insert into SecondTable
Select PersonID, r_num RoomID, isDecorared from FirstTable
Cross Apply (select top(100) row_number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1 r_num
             from sys.all_objects A , sys.all_objects B) X
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I took the 'union all' option as my case was quite simple (4 new rows for all existing rows) but cross apply looks very useful.